# 3 waves, calculate time of collective period?

Tags: waves, frequency

I have 3 sinusoidal waves. Frequencies 1.3, 0.8 and 1.5 Hz.
They all start at zero amplitude, at the same time.
How do I calculate the time it takes for my waves to meet at zero amplitude again, and hence repeat their collective period?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are required to find T such that it is an integer multiple of half periods, i.e.

$inf(l,m,n>0) : l/2.6 = m/1.6 = n/3$

$l/13=m/8=n/15=1$

Picking any value and evaluating that many half periods gives e time of 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm trying to create a function that takes my Hz' as arguments, and spits out the resulting time in seconds ... But, I'm having a hard time figuring out, how to do that.
If your answer leads me to a working result, I will accept it ... until then, God help me :)

Comment: In general it comes down to a lowest common multiple / greatest common divisor problem. If you are working with irrational numbers they will never meet, but anything floating point will be rational, though numerical accuracy may drastically effect an answer. Best if they input it as fractions rather than decimal values.